# How to create general Kubernetes objects from yaml using Java client

Tags: java, kubernetes

I want to create a service in Java which will take a yaml file and create whatever object is in there on a Kubernetes cluster.

Somewhat like how `kubectl create -f file.yaml` does.

The yaml file can contain a pod, service or deployment.

Can this be done in either official Kubernetes Java Client or fabric8 Kubernetes Java Client? How can it be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Kubernetes REST API](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/#/)

Example create new deployment:

```
curl -X POST -d @deployment.json -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer ${ACCESS_TOKEN}" ${API}/apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/${namespace}/deployments
```

Comment: I want to submit a yml file which can contain any object.